# How to display errors in for upon registration

Tags: php, registration

I made a user registration form and am now working on the error handling but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong.

So far I've made one error handler to check if password and confirm password upon registration do match, if not I need the error to display in the form. I would love to have the password match statement to be displayed in or under the form if the passwords in the registration form do not match, i would also love to add messages later to confirm if user exists or not or if fields are left empty.

1. My signup script:

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

       $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
       $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
       $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
       $cPassword = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cPassword');

       $options = [
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
          PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        ];


       if ($password != $cPassword)
           $msg = "Wachtwoord komt niet overeen!";
       else {
            $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$name, $email, $hash]);

            $msg = "U bent geregistreerd!";
            header( "Refresh:3; url=/Login2/inloggen.php", true, 303);
       }
   }
   ```
2. My form contains the following code and had the above file included:

   ```
     <?php

     require'includes/layouts/header.php';
     require'includes/signup.inc.php';

     ?>

     <div class="login-page">
     <div class="form">

     <?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
       <p><?= $error ?></p>
     <?php endforeach ?>

     <form class="login-form" action="registreren.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="name"/>
       <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail address" name="email"/>
       <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
       <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="cPassword"/>
       <button name="register" type="submit">create</button>
       <p class="message">Bent u al geregistreerd? <a 
       href="index.php">Keer terug</a></p>
       </form>
       </div>
       </div>

       <?php

       require'includes/layouts/footer.php';

       ?>
   ```

Comment: Syntax error! `<?php endforeach ?>` needs a semi colon like `<?php endforeach; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

In the signup script you create a (string) variable called `$msg` and then never use it. In the form you refer to a (array) variable called `$errors` which doesn't appear to be defined anywhere. The two things don't match up (either by name or by type), which is the obvious root of your issue.

Instead of

```
if ($password != $cPassword)
        $msg = "Wachtwoord komt niet overeen!";
```

try

```
$errors = array();
if ($password != $cPassword)
        $errors[] = "Wachtwoord komt niet overeen!";
```

P.S. You also have a syntax error as per the comments - make sure you write `<?php endforeach; ?>` - almost all lines of code in PHP must end with a semi-colon.

Comment: Ha, I missed the array issue completely, maybe its time for bed :)

Comment: The error variable is defined and used for the database connection, the problem is that i took the files apart to make it more mvc style. i'll work on this and get back to the point asap. thnx

Comment: It works now but I'm wondering if this piece of code is correct now (no idea how to put the code in nicely like you did)


```<?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
            <p>Wachtwoord komt niet overeen!</p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>```

Comment: It's correct in that it doesn't crash, but it does not make any logical sense to do it like that. You will just end up printing the same message as many times as there are items in the errors array, regardless of what the errors actually are

Comment: Oke, then it's time to figure out how to do this for multiple errors without having to print it Everytime, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to use `<?php foreach ($errors as $error): ?>
    <p><?= $error ?></p>
  <?php endforeach; ?>` as you had already. It will print each item in the errors array. Not sure why you ever changed it? All you have to do before is populate the array with relevant errors - and I've shown you how to populate the array with the message about the passwords my answer above.

Comment: Well that what I had, offcourse not exactly the same otherwise it would work lol, thanks a LOT for helping out!

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as accepted - thanks and good luck in future :-)